# Why can't I upvote comments?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Two days ago I found that I could not upvote any comments. I believe I have the priviledge; at least, I can comment everywhere and vote up/down. I see other comments getting voted up, so it looks like it's just me. Is there a problem with my account, or my computer, or what?

Comment: This seems to be resolved now - not sure why. Clearing my cache didn't seem to help, but I can upvote comments now for some random reason.

Answer (score 2):

We can't reproduce this; try clearing your browser's cache.

Answer (score 2):

Try a different browser, make sure you're updated, clear cookies, destroy global credentials.

Comment: Why the downvote?  How is this not helpful?