# Why was I downvoted?

Tags: discussion, support, votes

**NOTE: This is NOT a complaint question.  I would like to know how I can improve my asking/answering ability.**

In [this question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/606/why-cant-i-upvote-comments), what was wrong with my answer?

*Again: This is **NOT** a complaint question, I'm not asked for upvotes, I'm not asking for the downvote removed, I just want to learn how I can be a better contributing member of the SE community.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see anything inherently wrong with your answer. Nor do I see a pattern of poor answers or down-voting on your content. Sometimes down-votes are just somewhat… random. An isolate vote in either direction is not typically something to worry about.

I understand that the occasional random (even undeserved) down-vote can sting a bit. But, as you use the system and gain a bit of reputation, accounting for each and every point becomes less of a concern and you can better enjoy the use of the site. Consider for a moment that, for every undeserved down-vote, you've probably also received the occasional up-vote you didn't deserve either. Remember:

- Up-vote = +10 points
- Down-vote = -2 points

And in meta, down-votes don't cost *any* reputation. If the vote was not random, someone was simply saying they do not agree with your suggestion. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: +1: Good words of wisdom.  Thanks.

Comment: I love this: *Consider for a moment that, for every [un]deserved down-vote, you've probably also received the occasional up-vote .you didn't deserve either*

Answer (score 1):

Beyond Robert Cartaino's suggestions, it's also possible that the downvote signifies the answer did not work or help solve the problem, which implies the answer was not useful. That is, either the OP or someone having a similar problem did everything you suggested in your answer, but they still could not upvote comments.